# My image seems locked into a block display when I want it to overlay another image

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, z-index

Basically, I have a page that should load 3 pngs when you press the button. The problem I'm having is that I have one image #heart that I want to overlay onto a #background. I've tried different permutations of positioning but it (the #heart image) won't move at all, even with a high z-index over the lower layer. It won't even move to the right with left: x px

Sorry. I'm still pretty new. I'm completely stuck as to how to proceed. Developer tools just tell me that it's sitting in an image div above where I want it to be...  Here's the code:

```css
#heart {
   z-index: 99999;
   left: 200px;
   top: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
    position: relative;
   }

#background {
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: none;
 z-index: -10;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="action">
  <img id="heart" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725918/virtual%20pet/l1.png"  alt="heart points image">

  <img id="background" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561670551/virtual%20pet/little-board.png" alt="pin board image">

  <div id="bennyNormal"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: make the `#heart { position: absolute; }`

Answer (score 0):

To make this you will have to use some others `css` properties like `flex` and `background-image` and update you HTML DOM just like this:

```css
#heart {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#background {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561670551/virtual%20pet/little-board.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <div class="action">
  <div id="background"> 
    <img id="heart" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725918/virtual%20pet/l1.png"  alt="heart points image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give an element "position: relative", it keeps it's place in the document flow, so when you change it's position on the page with top: 100px or whatever, it moves but the space it vacates is not removed from the document. Therefore, nothing moves in to take it's place and z-index does nothing.

Try this:

```
 <div class="action">
    // Switch the two images in the document flow to make this             easier, although you can ignore that if you want.

    <img id="background" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561670551/virtual%20pet/little-board.png" alt="pin board image">

 <img id="heart" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725918/virtual%20pet/l1.png"  alt="heart points image">


    <div id="bennyNormal"></div>

  </div>
```

So now, #heart is no longer "below" the #background image in the document flow. bennyNormal div is still "above" everything inside the #action div but because the #background image comes first (with a relative position (or even if it had no position) #background will keep the div below it on the page in the doc flow. If you also give #background display: block it will stop the div from moving up, if that ever becomes an issue.

Then:

```
 #heart {
z-index: 99999; <== this is irrelevant now. get rid of it.
left: 200px; <== change these to position over #background as you wish
top: 100px;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
position: absolute; <== important bit.
}

#background {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: none;   <== You want it invisible? Should be block.
z-index: -10;  <= Same with this. Don't screw around with z-index if you can avoid it.
position: relative; <== This no longer matters, but you can still include it
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As nitin9nair comment, setting #heart { position: absolute; } seems to be enough

```css
#heart {
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:320px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="action">

  <img id="heart" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561725918/virtual%20pet/l1.png"  alt="heart points image">
  <img id="background" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1561670551/virtual%20pet/little-board.png" alt="pin board image">

  <div id="bennyNormal"></div>

</div>
```